# Cramer's V - example and intuition

Tags: statistics

Hy, I self study statistics and I come across Cramer's V and I search on Google. The result I find didn't explain me so I please to answer this questions.
What is measured by Cramer's V? What is an example when Cramer's V is equal to 0 and an example when is 1?

Answer (score 5):

Cramér's V is a measure of association.

If you have a $k\times m$ contingency table, you can apply a $\chi^2$ calculation and test with $(k-1)(m-1)$ degrees of freedom which may lead you to believe the two sets of factors are not independent, but that does not tell you how associated the values are.  The calculated $\chi^2$ value depends on the overall sample size (the larger the sample size, the higher $\chi^2$ is and so the more likely you are to reject the null hypothesis) and is affected by the number of rows and columns in the table.  Cramér's V attempts to adjust for these.

The first step is to take into account the size of the data set.  If there are $n$ observations in total then consider $\frac{\chi^2}{n}$.  This can range from $0$ to $\min(k-1,m-1)$.  So now consider $\frac{1}{\min(k-1,m-1)}\frac{\chi^2}{n}$, which can ranges from $0$ to $1$. It turns out that if $k=m=2$ then this is equivalent to $r^2$, the square of a correlation coefficient, so it might be worth considering taking the square root, still with a possible range of $0$ to $1$.

So (at least before adjusting for other issues), Cramér's V is defined as $$V=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\min(k-1,m-1)}\frac{\chi^2}{n}}$$

Here are a couple of invented examples based on the colours of shapes

```
    circle  star square
red      0   0   100
yellow   0  300   0
green    0   0   400
blue    200  0    0
```

If you calculate this you get $\chi^2=2000$ and $n=1000$ and $\min(k-1,r-1)=2$, so $V=\sqrt{\frac12 \frac{2000}{1000}}=1$.  This is plausible, as knowing the colour tells you the shape with certainty.

By contrast

```
    circle  star square
red     20   30   50
yellow  60   90  150
green   80  120  200
blue    40   60  100
```

If you calculate this you get $\chi^2=0$ and $n=1000$ and $\min(k-1,r-1)=2$, so $V=\sqrt{\frac12 \frac{0}{1000}}=0$.  This is plausible, as knowing the colour tells nothing additional about the possible shape.